# Locally free resolution of coherent sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi everybody,

how does one prove the following statement:

given a coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on a smooth projective variety $X$, then $\mathscr{F}$ has a resolution by locally free sheaves of length $n=\dim(X)$.

Or does anybody know a reference for this fact?

Greetings!

Comment: I am no expert here, but Hartshorne Exercise III 6.8 and Auslander-Buchsbaum formula seem to do the trick (for more general situation). 

Comment: This is the celebrated "Hilbert syzygy theorem".

You can find a discussion in [Griffiths-Harris, Principles of Algebraic Geometry, Chapter 5 section 4].

The starting point of the proof is that the global sections $H^0(X, \mathscr{F}(k))$ generate each $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{F}(k)_x$ $(x \in X)$ for $k$ big enough. 

Comment: If you like commutative algebra, the statement is the "sheafication" of the corresponding statement for finitely generated moduli over polynomial rings, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_syzygy_theorem

Comment: Deleted my answer, and added comment instead. Actually this question, given its rather elementary nature, should have been posted at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Francesco, while I agree that this is pretty standard,
I'm not quite sure that I would call it Hibert's syzygy theorem
exactly -- you do need Auslander-Buschsbaum-Serre to stop the
process.

Comment: Dear Donu, I agree with you. However some people call "Hilbert syzygy theorem" also  this sheaf-theoretic version, for instance G. Ottaviani in his nice book "Varità proiettive di codimensione piccola" (Projective varieties of small codimension, in italian). By the way, the "Hilbert syzygy theorem" of commutative algebra one should refer in this case is the graded version: given $S=k[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$, then the $(n+1)$-th syzygy module of any graded $S$-module $M$ is free. 

Comment: I on the other hand feel that I must disagree with Donu. Applying
Hilbert's syszygy theorem to a (finitely generated) graded module
whose $\widetilde{(-)}$ is the given $\mathbb F$ gives exactly what
the OP asked (by applying $\widetilde{(-)}$ to the
resolution). Auslander-Buchsbaum-Serre is generalising Hilbert's
theorem to more general situations.